# How to call custom methods in AppDelegate whenever any view controller is appear or disappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I know that `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` methods are called whenever a particular view controller appears and disappears.

I want an `AppDelegate` method to be called whenever *any* view controller in the application appears or disappears.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should update your question with more specific details about what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overriding UIViewController (which would mandate that all your view controllers must inherit from it, and thus introduces tight coupling) instead you can create an extension for UIViewController and swizzle viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear.

This link has all the details and code required to swizzle a UIViewController in Swift

http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

It provides the code to swizzle viewWillAppear.You would call your app delegate method in the xxx_viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 0):

First, subclass UIViewController that will incorporate this functionality. All view controllers will inherit from this new class. Second, write your public method in your appDelegate as desired. Third, make your custom method as follows:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppNameAppDelegate{
        appDelegate.doCustomMethod()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sausage Modulation Matrix says, this is view controller category which is help you. `new_viewWillAppear:` or `new_viewWillDisappear:` call commonly when `UIViewController` life cycle method call.
In this swizzle method you can execute appDelegate methods as per your requirements.

## UIViewController+ViewControllerSwizzle.m

```
#import "UIViewController+ViewControllerSwizzle.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

void standard_swizzle(Class cls, SEL original, SEL replacement) {
    Method originalMethod;
    if ((originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(cls, original)))
    {
        Method replacementMethod = class_getClassMethod(cls, replacement);
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, replacementMethod);
    }
    else
    {
        IMP replacementImplementation = method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod(cls, replacement), class_getMethodImplementation(cls, original));
        if (!class_addMethod(cls, original, replacementImplementation, method_getTypeEncoding(class_getInstanceMethod(cls, replacement)))) method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod(cls, original), replacementImplementation);
    }
}


@implementation UIViewController (ViewControllerSwizzle)

+(void)load
{
    if (self == [UIViewController class]) {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            NSArray *methods = @[@"viewWillAppear:", @"viewWillDisappear:"];

            for (NSString* methodName in methods) {
                standard_swizzle(self, NSSelectorFromString(methodName), NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"new_%@", methodName]));
            }
        });
    }

}

-(void)new_viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self new_viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[AppDelegate sharedManager] viewWillAppearStuff]; //AppDelegate custom method.
}
-(void)new_viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self new_viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[AppDelegate sharedManager] viewWillDisppearStuff]; //AppDelegate custom method.
}

@end
```

Here is simple AppDelegate stuff:

## AppDelegate.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

+(AppDelegate *)sharedManager;
-(void)viewWillAppearStuff;
-(void)viewWillDisppearStuff;
@end
```

## AppDelegate.m file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

+(AppDelegate *)sharedManager
{
    static AppDelegate *sharedMyManager = nil;
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedMyManager == nil)
        {
            sharedMyManager = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        }
    }
    return sharedMyManager;
}
-(void)viewWillAppearStuff
{
    /*
     Do Something.
     */
}
-(void)viewWillDisppearStuff
{
    /*
     Do Something.
     */
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Since Objective-C class methods can't be called from Swift 3.1 and up, it will need a different approach. I made this to swizzle viewWillDisappear to stop a spinner from spinning.

```
extension UIViewController {

    @objc func viewWillDisappearOverride(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.viewWillDisappearOverride(animated) //Incase we need to override this method

        if self.isMovingFromParent {
            SpinnerManager.shared.stopSpinner()
        }
    }

    static func swizzleViewWillDisappear() {
    //Make sure This isn't a subclass of UIViewController, So that It applies to all UIViewController childs
        if self != UIViewController.self {
            return
        }
        let _: () = {
            let originalSelector = #selector(UIViewController.viewWillDisappear(_:))
            let swizzledSelector = #selector(UIViewController.viewWillDisappearOverride(_:))
            guard let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector),
                let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector) else { return }
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }()
    }
}
```

and then to activate it I just called `UIViewController.swizzleViewWillDisappear()` from AppDelegate from inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`